# Como conectar o Oracle ao Java? Aparece esse erro "Erro ao registrar: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"

Tags: java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection c;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521: XE";
        String usuario = "SYSTEM";
        String senha = "BANCO_OPET";
        String sql = "";

        try {;
            // 1º estabelecer a conexao
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, senha);
            System.out.println("Conectou com sucesso");

            rs.close();
            ps.close();
            c.close();
            System.out.println("Fechou a conexão");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao conectar: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao registrar: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente o driver não está no classpath.

A forma de adicionar ao classpath vai depender da sua configuração (Eclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJ Idea, Maven, Gradle, arquivos .jar adicionados na mão, etc...).